# How to connect a WPF Combobox to KeyValue-Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox

I'm struggeling with a WPF Combobox.
My job is to let the user select an entry, that should be stored in a variable and additionally it is possible, that this variable is changed programatically, so the combobox should selct the corresponding item.

First my code:

```
public KeyValuePair<string, string> SelectedLanguage { get; set; }   //the selected item
public Dictionary<string, string> Languages { get; set; }            //the list of combobox items

private void loadLanguages(List<string> languages)
{
    Languages = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach(string language in languages)
    {
        //set initial selected item
        if(language=="de_DE") SelectedLanguage = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(language, getLanguageDescription(language));
        Languages.Add(language, getLanguageDescription(language));
    }
 }

private string getLanguageDescription(string language)
{
    switch (language)
    {
        case "de_DE_Match":
            return "Deutsch";
        case "fr_FR_Match":
            return "Französisch (Frankreich)";
        case "nl_NL_Match":
            return "Niederländisch";
        case "en_EN_Match":
            return "Englisch (GB)";
        default:
            return "unbekannt";
    }
 }
```

And this is my WPF:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbLanguages" 
    ItemsSource ="{Binding Languages}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedLanguage}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedLanguage.Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Now the List is shown as expected but there is no item selected, inside the textbox, the SelectedLanguage is shown correctly but not changed if selection of the combobox changes.

So how can I programmatically change the selected item and how can I show the selected item in the textbox? Shouldn't it be enough, if I change the SelectedLanguage?

Comment: Just change the type of SelectedLanguage to string

Comment: Have you tried `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedLanguage.Key}"`?

Comment: or `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage}"`

Comment: Thanks, @GazTheDestroyer... SelectedItem was the right hint. Now Propertychanged is fired and textbox is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ItemsSource ="{Binding Languages}"
```

ok, so you have a combo box that contains a collection of `KeyValuePair`s, since `Languages` is a dictionary.

```
DisplayMemberPath="Value"
```

This says that the text displayed for each item will be the `Value` of the `KeyValuePair`, (the language description)

```
SelectedValuePath="Key"
```

This says that when selecting items with SelectedValue, we should be comparing against the `Key` of the `KeyValuePair`. (the language code)

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedLanguage}" />
```

This binds the selection to `SelectedLanguage`, which should be a language code (string) as we just specified. However, `SelectedLanguage` is not a string, but a `KeyValuePair`. Since your ItemsSource is already a collection of KeyValuePairs, you don't need to worry about `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue` at all, you can just use `SelectedItem`.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbLanguages" 
          ItemsSource ="{Binding Languages}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```